# Generating a (non-unique) Random list

Tags: python, aptana

I am using Python 2.7 and I want to generate a non-unique list.  I am trying:

```
from random import randint
from random import random

a= random.sample(range(100),15)

print a
```

I get this error
 a= random.sample(range(100),15)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'sample'

Answer (score 2):

When you do `from random import random` you're actually importing the specific [`random.random()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.random) function in the `random` module. You don't want to do this - you only want to import the module:

```
import random
a = random.sample(range(100), 15)
print a
```

Comment: be aware, other then asked, this generates a unique random list

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting an error is because you're importing the function `random.random` when you say `from random import random`. `random` is no longer the name of the module, it now refers to the function.

If you want to use the syntax `random.sample` you should just do `import random`. If you want to just use `sample` (i.e. `a = sample(range(100),15)`) do `from random import sample`.

As for getting a list of non-unique random ints in the interval [1, 100], try:

```
a = [random.randint(1, 100) for _ in range(15)]
```